# Why does the OTA installation fails for iOS apps in IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-qa

The OTA installation of iOS apps is failing in iOS devices. Is there any prerequisite for OTA distribution of iOS apps in IBM MobileFirst Quality Assurance?

Answer (score 0):

There might be many reasons on why the installation is failing. Most important of them all is the following two reasons:

1. Not using a secure connection to the server for OTA installation. Make sure that you use (https) and also install the SSL certificate on the device.
2. Not registering the device within the provisioning profile. The device needs to be registered.